# Lower bound function with simpler function

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, upper-lower-bounds, weierstrass-approximation

From wikipedia,

$$
D(x \| y)=x \ln \frac{x}{y}+(1-x) \ln \left(\frac{1-x}{1-y}\right)
$$
is the Kullback-Leibler divergence between Bernoulli distributed random variables with parameters $x$ and $y$ respectively.

I need to solve for $\epsilon$ in equations of the form $$D(p+ \epsilon \| p)=n$$ for $0<n,0\leq p\leq 1$.

**I don't think an analytical solution exists for this equation. (Is there?)**

My next thought was to find a function $f(x,y)\leq D(x \| y)$ for which an analytical solution could be found out for $\epsilon$ in
$$f(p+\epsilon,p)=n,$$

since a lower bound will suffice for my application.

The tightest lower bound that I could find (which produced an analytical solution) was,

$$D_{1 / 2}(x \| y)=-2 \log \left(\sqrt{xy}+\sqrt{(1-x)(1-y))}\right)$$

belonging to the family of [Renyi divergences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9nyi_entropy#R%C3%A9nyi_divergence).

**Since KL divergence is a well studied function I expect there to some known result on this. Is there any known solution to this problem?**

**If not, how to tackle this problem?**

EDIT

My question is in relation to the Chernoff bounds. See my question (and answer) to the [question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53412/67196) on TCS stackexchange.